# Apache .htaccess redirection

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please help me with the redirection of a page.

*Current URL* - http://example.com/my-goat-eats-grass

I also want this URL - http://example.com/example-text-my-goat-eats-grass

to redirect to

`http://example.com/my-goat-eats-grass`

I am using WordPress.

Comment: Can't you rename the page?

Comment: It doesn't physically exists it is also kind of redirection by wordpress

i just want to redirect this new url http://example.com/example-text-my-goat-eats-grass to old one

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the URL is specific, just add a Redirect rule:

```
Redirect permanent /example-text-my-goat-eats-grass /my-goat-eats-grass
```

But if it is a set of urls, with a fixed prefix, you could do something like this

```
RewriteRule ^example-text-(.+)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

This way every url starting with `example-text-` will be redirect to the url with the `example-text-` part stripped out.

The `[R=301]` part makes sure the user is redirect with a 301 (permanent) http code, so google will know the page is actually moved (and you will not get a duplicate content penalty)

Examples:

```
/example-text-my-goat-eats-grass          -> /my-goat-eats-grass
/example-text-my-goat-eats-pigs           -> /my-goat-eats-pigs
/example-text-my-goat-eats-grass/and/pigs -> /my-goat-eats-grass/and/pigs
```

**Edit**

A short explanation of the rule. Full explanation is way beyond the scope of this question/answer, please refer to the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/) for this topic.

Basically a rewrite rule looks like this:

```
RewriteRule pattern substitution [flags]
```

The pattern is a regular expression that matches the url. If it does not match, the rule will be ignored and it'll go on to the next rules. If it *does* match, the url will be rewritten conforming the subsitution part. In it's most easy form, a rule could look like this:

```
RewriteRule substitute-this by-this
```

Now if anyone requests the URL `example.com/substitute-this` the user will be redirected to the url `example.com/by-this`. In my example above I have added the sign `^`, which means, `starting with`. Because in my easy example, also `example.com/foobar-substitute-this` will be rewritten to `example.com/by-this`, *because apache matched an url with* substitute-this *in it*.

Then I added a *I don't care what comes next* part (the `(.*`)) (more specifically: match all characters), and in the substitute part I used a variable (`$1`) to say, print here the piece that was matched by the *I don't care what comes next*-part.

Then lastly there are two flags: `R=301` to redirect with the http 301 status code (redirect permanent), and `L` (the Last flag) to prevent from other rewriterules down below to take effect whenever this rule was matched.

I hope this helps a bit, but yet again, for full and proper understanding, refer to the documentation or other resources

Comment: funny, I tested it and it works like a charm... maybe you forgot to set the RewriteBase? Maybe other rules conflict? can you post your full .htaccess (stripped out privacy parts) including this rule?

Comment: AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php .php5 .php4 .php3

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^example-text-(.*) $1 [R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Ok, try to insert the `RewriteRule` AFTER the `RewriteBase` directive. And add the `L` flag just to be sure (see my edited example)

Comment: can u pls explain the line you have written

Comment: bro if i want to do opposite of it then how would i be able to do it like

`/my-goat-eats-grass          -> /example-text-my-goat-eats-grass`

Comment: Please Answer Brother  I am waiting

i want to do opposite of it then how would i be able to do it like `/my-goat-eats-grass -> /example-text-my-goat-eats-grass`

Comment: I don't like the `I am waiting` part

Comment: Sorry bro I am in a hurry kind of pressure bcoz my google traffic is redirecting to `404 Page`

so i just want to save reputation of my website.
don't take it in other manner...

U r a star for me... Real Star

Comment: Well, the quick-and-dirt solution would be to just turn it around: `RewriteRule ^(.*) example-text-$1 [R=301,L]`. But remember: this will redirect ALL of your url's to `example-text-....`. You might need some `RewriteCond`'s for this, but that's beyond the scope of the question as well

Comment: so if i have link like 

`http://example.com/my-cat-loves-me/`

then redirect to
 
`http://example.com/example-text-my-cat-loves-me/`

and if my url is like

`http://example.com/2014/02/`

or 
`http://example.co/category/abc-xyz/`
or
`http://example.co/tags/abc-xyz/`
then simply dont redirect

Comment: @girgio above code is looping to `example-text-example-text-example-text-...`

Please help

Comment: yeah could be, see the altered rule above

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin called [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/), that should be able to achieve this. After installing the plugin go to:

- Tools -> Redirection
- In the "Source URL" box add "http://example.com/example-text-my-goat-eats-grass"
- In the "Target URL" box add "http://example.com/my-goat-eats-grass"
- Next click on the "Add redirection" button and the old page should redirect to the new page.

The above method saves you trying to edit the .htaccess file.

To match dynamic links, then

- In the "Redirect From:" box add "http://example.com/example-text-*"
- In the "Redirect To:" box add "/"
- Then tick the "Regex" box
- Next click on the "Add redirection" button and the old page should redirect to the new page.

The above will redirect "http://example.com/example-text-cats-and-dogs" to "http://example.com/cats-and-dogs

Comment: it looks promising but can i do it for dynamic links?

Comment: Ok thanks howlin it was wonderful knowing about this wonderful plug

Comment: Sorry, check my edit I think it can do what you want with the dynamic links

Comment: bro if i want to do opposite of it then how would i be able to do it like `/my-goat-eats-grass -> /example-text-my-goat-eats-grass`

Answer (score 1):

In .htaccess you can add the following line

```
Redirect 301 /example-text-my-goat-eats-grass /my-goat-eats-grass
```

Comment: brother it should work dynamically there are thousands of urls like this i want to add one static prefix to all the url.. but keeping previous url alive